# Parsing error: No Babel config file detected

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a project in vue. But I get this problem after I create a project.

`Parsing error: No Babel config file detected for C:\\HotelManagmet\clienthotel\babel.config.js. Either disable config file checking with requireConfigFile: false, or configure Babel so that it can find the config files.`
I can not solve it, I have tried to reinstall node.js and visual studio code but the problem remains. Have tried running npm audit fix --force but unfortunately the result is the same. Anyone know what it could be?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had the same issue and this change fixed the issue.
In your `.eslintrc.js` file, add `requireConfigFile: false`

```
parserOptions: {
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  requireConfigFile: false, // <== ADD THIS
  ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
  sourceType: 'module' // Allows for the use of imports
}
```

Comment: Note: `parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',` needs to be defined outside `parserOptions`

Comment: Hey, @pradeep, what if we do not have such .eslintrc.js file? In Vue3 the eslint configuration is made in the package.json file, by default.

Comment: @Vitomir https://babeljs.io/docs/configuration#packagejson

Comment: @Saibamen I think it depends on the `eslint` version, I had to define `parser` inside `parserOptions`

Comment: In Vue 3. The ` "requireConfigFile": false` needs to be added to package.json in the `parseOperation` section.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution 1**

The most important:***babel.config.js*** should in your root directory.
it's means if you have such structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4ZEA.png)

```
root directory
    --your project1
    |
    |--src
    |--nodemodules
    |--babel.config.js
    --your project2
    |
    |--src
    |--nodemodules
    |--babel.config.js
```

if you run the project,it would show the error.
so if you want to run the project1 or project2,just open it,and then make sure it as root directory.

**Solution 2**

open the .eslintrc.js, and alter the root value like:

```
root:'',
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
      "requireConfigFile": false // add this in package.json for Vue3
    },
```

Comment: could you please explain what this will do?

Answer (score 1):

If you do have a babel config file or you want to define one, you can just link it to your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "babelOptions": {
      "configFile": "/absolute/path/to/babel.config.js"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was happening when I tried to run the linter inside a container using the absolute path of my computer. Making sure to update to the correct path depending on the environment fixed the issue for me.

```
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "babelOptions": {
      "cwd": "/absolute/path/to/"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **VS Code**, go to it's `settings.json` and add `"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]`. It's explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZ9nIiRVRfE&t=71s).

In my `eslintrc` file, I had to insert `'env': {'node': true},` and remove `'sourceType': 'module'`.

Answer (score -1):

In your terminal, run `npm install`. Then, replace your `babel.config.js` contents with below:

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this command really complete? I miss the opening bracket `{`

Comment: Should start with: `module.exports = {`